# Page 'jumps' when menu goes from relative to fixed with fadein/out - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, menu

I'm losing lot of time trying to make a scroll event to get my header/nav detached and fixed on top of the page when the scroll reaches it.

The menu with fadeOut() goes `"display: none"`, and my page goes up the height of the nav.
How can I get a smooth movement?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){     
  if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.offset().top-menu.height() && menu.hasClass('menudefault')){        
    menu.fadeOut('500', function(){             
    $(this).addClass('menufixed').removeClass('menudefault').fadeIn('500');
  });
}
```

here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/WbQxrZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to make a clone of the menu in order to keep the layout unchanged. And then operate on the clone.

DEMO http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPYXLO

```
var menuClone = $();
if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.offset().top-menu.height() && menuClone.length==0){
//                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    menuClone = menu.clone().appendTo('body').removeClass('menudefault').addClass('menufixed').hide().fadeIn('400');
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menuClone.length>0){ 
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    menuClone.fadeOut('100', function(){             
        menuClone.remove();
        menuClone = $();
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

I suggest to get rid of `menuClone.fadeOut()`, just remove the clone `menuClone.remove(); menuClone = $();`

Comment: Right! I was trying to clone it but in a bad way. This is what I was looking for. I just removed the quotes to get the right fade value, like `fadeIn(400)` . Now it's perfect!

Comment: I've got also some problems adding images on top. Solved with this:

[http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/jEbVqq](http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/jEbVqq)

Answer (score 0):

```
menu.fadeOut('500', function(){ etc...
```

Your 500 should not have '' around it. You have this twice actually. Once in your fadeOut effect and your fadeIn effect. 500 is not a string it is a value. You need a value.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){     
  if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.offset().top-menu.height() && menu.hasClass('menudefault')){        
   menu.fadeOut(500, function(){             
    $(this).addClass('menufixed').removeClass('menudefault').fadeIn(500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a totally different approach. With this approach we clone the original menu and append the clone right before it so that way there is always an element occupying the space, therefore preventing the page from jumping.

- JSBin: http://jsbin.com/tuxogolefa/4/edit?js,output
- JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usve8wm8/

---

The JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var 
    $menu = $('#menu'),
    $clone = $menu.clone(true),
    $window = $(window),
    top = $menu.offset().top,
    topDown = top + $menu.height(),
    currentScroll = 0;

    $clone.addClass('fixed');
    $menu.before($clone);

    $window.scroll(function() {
      currentScroll = $window.scrollTop();

      if(currentScroll > topDown) {
        $menu.addClass('invisible');
        $clone.addClass('visible');
      } 

      if(currentScroll < top) {
        $menu.removeClass('invisible');
        $clone.removeClass('visible');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The CSS:

```
body {margin:0; padding: 1em;}
#menu {
  background: #e55;
}
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
}
.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Careers</li>
    <li>More</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks perfect! I can't wait to use it!